# Use BertTokenizer with HuggingFace GPT-2

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, gpt-2

I have a specific generation problem involving a dataset built from a very small vocabulary. Ideally, my use case will be much more straightforward if I can simply provide that vocabulary in a fixed set of tokens. I know that with the BertTokenizer, for example, I can provide a `vocab.txt` file and avoid any further tokenization of this basic vocabulary, and I'm wondering if there's a way to get GPT-2 to do the same? The only thing I can think of right now is creating a hacked `PretrainedTokenizer` subclass, but perhaps someone has a better idea?

Any thoughts appreciated.

UPDATE: Okay, so it turns out I can just swap out `BertTokenizer` and `BertWordpieceTokenizer` when creating the `GPT2LMHeadModel`. (Thanks HuggingFace for a well-designed, modular codebase!)